# Windows 7 does not recognise second display output

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I've got a PC with dual BenQ G2222HDL monitors and an ATI Radeon HD 4650 video card. I've been running both monitors at 1920x1080 for some months now but last week the second monitor switched to a lower resolution and won't let me go back to 1920x1080.

If I right click the Desktop and choose Screen Resolution from the menu, I get two items in the Display: drop down list

1. BenQ G2222HDL D-SUB
2. Display device on: VGA

In the past 2 was always the same as 1.

If I click Detect a third item appears

Available display output on: ATI Radeon HD 4650

but if I use the Multiple displays: drop down list to use it says "No display detected" and then lets me choose from either "Connect anyway on S-Video" or "Connect anyway on Component", neither of which help.

It seems like Windows 7 recognises the card is dual-head, and knows I have got two monitors, but can't link it all together. I have checked and all my drivers are up-to-date.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can get the second monitor working properly again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are using VGA to connect to the monitor?

I would personally use DVI/HDMI for both monitors, but it looks like you only have DVI/HDMI port.

My first thing would be to try a different VGA cable, to see if the connector/cable is the problem.

Comment: Thanks, the cabling was the problem. I had two VGA cables with a DVI dongle on the end of each, so they could connect to the video card. I've now purchased two proper DVI cables and all is well.